# stop Terraform to load modules automatically

Tags: terraform

In my terraform directory I have a module defined in a folder named "modules/dev-only" in which I want to create resources for development purposes only.

To deploy the module, I used the command `terraform apply --target module.dev-only` where a module was described in a file with `source = ./modules/dev-only`

I don't know what happened, but now the command `terraform apply` (with no target defined) is including the module in the configuration. This means that terraform is considering all subfolders in the apply operation, and I need to stop this! Please, help :)

Comment: Some more clarity is needed. What is meant by "only terraform apply is including the module in the configuration, and I need to stop this"?
Does Terraform not see changes to other `.tf` files you are making?

Please share more details of your situation, so that we can assess what's going on.

Comment: This means that terraform is looking for all .tf files in the root folder, but also in all subfolders that contain only modules. The command `terraform apply` is considering all subfolders structure instead of only the root folder

Comment: Still I am not sure what exactly you are facing. Are you sure you are in the right directory (i.e. what you call the root directory) when issuing the `terraform apply`?

Comment: It is where are all .tf and .tfvars files. They are all in a flat structure in the same folder that I am calling root.

The module is different, the files from a module are in a subfolder. There is a `modules.tf` in the root folder, alongside with all files, with a module description, pointing the source to the subfolder of the module. As I understand, terraform does not check subfolders even if a module is defined, so that's what is breaking my code

Answer (score 1):

In Terraform there is a distinction between a module call itself -- the `module` block -- and the zero-or-more *module instances* it declares. If you write a `module` block *without* either the [`count`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/count.html) or [`for_each`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html) meta-arguments then there will be exactly one instance of the module, but you can use either of those meta-arguments to customize the number of instances and declare the differences in their input variables using expressions.

What you've described sounds like one particular example of that capability: you want to declare one instance of the module in a "dev" situation, and zero instances of the module in other situations. To achieve that, you can add the `count` argument to the module call using an expression that will evaluate to `1` in the "dev" situation and `0` in all other situations.

There are lots of ways to write such an expression, but a straightforward answer is to declare an optional input variable which you'll set only for the "dev" situation, and which can potentially carry any special settings that only need to be set in that case:

```
variable "dev_settings" {
  type = object({
    # you can declare dev-specific attributes in here,
    # if needed.
  })
  # this is an optional variable that will be null
  # if not explicitly set.
  default = null
}
```

I wrote an object [type constraint](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/type-constraints.html) above, although I didn't declare any attributes in it and so the only possible values for it as currently defined are `{}` (an empty object) or `null`. If you have additional settings that are required in the development situation, such as perhaps a unique prefix to allow multiple developers to create their own concurrent instances of the configuration during development, you could declare those in there as additional attributes.

To use this variable, write your module block with a `count` expression like this:

```
module "dev_only" {
  source = "../modules/dev_only"
  count  = length(var.dev_settings[*])

  # (and any other arguments the module requires)
}
```

The `count` expression above is using [the splat operator](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/splat.html) in the [Single Values as Lists](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/splat.html#single-values-as-lists) mode, which means that a `null` value will become an empty list `[]` and a non-null value will become a one-element list containing that value. That therefore achieves the desired result of setting `count` to 1 only if `var.dev_settings` is set to a non-null object.

Note that Terraform uses a "desired state" methodology where it will create a plan to move from your current state to the desired state described by your configuration. That means that if you initially run `terraform apply` using a variables file that sets `dev_settings` and then later run `terraform apply` again *against that same state* Terraform will propose to *destroy* the resource instances associated with the module previously created. You'll therefore need to be consistent about how you set that variable for each different state you work with.

---

Temporary "copies" of infrastructure for development can be a good use-case for [workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/state/workspaces.html), which allows you to have multiple separate states associated with the same configuration, stored as different objects in the same backend. and switch between them.

If you decide to use workspaces then you might decide that the "default" workspace (the one that always exists) represents your main state that tracks your real infrastructure, while every other workspace name is a temporary one for development. In that case, you could potentially drop the explicit input variable and instead make decisions based on [the `terraform.workspace` symbol](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/state/workspaces.html#current-workspace-interpolation), which evaluates to the name of the currently-selected workspace.

```
locals {
  dev_mode = (terraform.workspace != "default")
}

module "dev_only" {
  source = "../modules/dev_only"
  count  = local.dev_mode ? 1 : 0

  # (and any other arguments the module requires)
}
```

This approach has the advantage that you no longer need to carefully-coordinate input variable values with which environment you're working in. Instead, you can use the workspace commands to create a new temporary workspace for development, use it for as long as you need to, and then destroy it:

```
# (assuming you start in the "default" workspace)
$ terraform workspace new dev-videap
Created and switched to workspace "dev-videap"!

You're now on a new, empty workspace. Workspaces isolate their state,
so if you run "terraform plan" Terraform will not see any existing state
for this configuration.

$ terraform apply
...

$ terraform destroy
...

$ terraform workspace select default
$ terraform workspace delete dev-videap
```

Because the `dev-videap` workspace will have its own state, you can apply and destroy against it as much as you like without affecting the `default` workspace. The `dev_only` module has an instance only when in a workspace with a name _other than "default", so switching to a different workspace name is all that you should need to activate it.

Workspaces are not appropriate for all situations. For more information, please review [When to use Multiple Workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/state/workspaces.html#when-to-use-multiple-workspaces) in the Terraform documentation.